# Get variables of a view?

Tags: views, hooks

im trying to access some variables of my view but i fail terribly:
My modulefile looks like this:

```
$io= views_get_view('nameofmyview');
dpm($io);
```

Drupal tells me:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function views_get_view()

What am i missing?

Comment: When you say "My modulefile looks like this", do you mean that literally or is your code inside a function?

Comment: @Clive I'm afraid i mean literally! And i have my views module activated...;-)

Comment: That's the problem then :) Drupal works on a hook system, code that's directly in a module file will be parsed and run when the file is included, and obviously in this case that's happening before the views module is included. Obviously at the moment you're just testing to see if code snippets work, but what do you ultimately want to do with that code?

Comment: @clive thanks for your kind help. I'm kind of depressed because of the complexity of the drupal structure. What i finally want to do: I built a view assembling some image fields of a ceratain content-type. The purpose of that thing ist to have ultimatly some slideshows on the first page with the http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/royal-slider/ slideshow. I want to hand over the image urls to the slider via json (php->javascript) due to dynamic loading and initialization of the slideshow...and i really need this slideshow because my customer wants it ;-( I really appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @clive for the hint

```
module_load_include('module','views','views');
```

does the trick!